# Definition of Profinite Groups.

Tags: profinite-groups

We know that totally disconnected topological groups are Hausdorff. Then why we are considering both Hausdorff and totally disconnected conditions in the definition of   profinite groups.

[Topological Group $G$ totally disconnected $\Rightarrow$ $G$ hausdorff?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550473/topological-group-g-totally-disconnected-rightarrow-g-hausdorff)